# SQL error with custom query (Wordpress)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm just making a custom post query on wordpress. Query working well but im giving an error message on debug file;

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1' at line 1

SQL query that;

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

How can I fix that? What is the right query for that any idea?

Comment: That query has no syntax errors in it. Are you sure this is the query that's causing the error?

Comment: Are the missing spaces (such as `'publish'OR` ) actually in your query or just typos from copying into your question?  If they're actually missing in your query, try putting spaces where they belong.

Comment: @ShiraNai7 Yes, im using "Query Monitor" plugin for wordpress and gives that error message :/

Comment: @devlincarnate Thanks for determination but thats just typos from copying into question. Originaly query has rows and no space. Are you thinking is that query has no syntax errors in it? Thanks again.

Comment: @OnurK. - that query appears to be syntactically correct, which is why I questioned the spaces.  You might try putting a blank space at the end of every row.  I know in languages where you can concatenate a string, you have to watch out for spacing on multi-line strings.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly you want to retrieve?

Comment: After where your condition is 1=1 actually condition should be like field_name = value

Comment: @devlincarnate Just added space end of rows but nothing changed :(

Comment: @HiralSuvagya Hello and thanks for suggestion. May you please give me an example about the condition. I'am just trying to list wp-post with optimized_post option.

Comment: i am still thinking why you put condition 1=1?